# How to combine dynamic routes and static routes in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm creating a react native wizard, and I want to combine my static route and wizard dynamic routes.

Currently I am using react navigation, and the major problem is i have a `generateNavigator`  function that creates the dynamic routes based on the props passed down to `Route.js` component where the function exists. I have tried moving the function to the `AppNavigator` where the static routes exists but am getting navigator must be a function. I'm running the app expo

Route.js

```js
generateNavigator = () => {
  const { steps, title } = this.props;
  const navigationRoutes = {};
  steps.forEach((step, index) => {
    const routeOptions = { screen: step.component };
    navigationRoutes[step.routeName] = routeOptions;
  });

  const navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    headerTintColor: '#111111',
    headerTitle: title,
  };

  return createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(navigationRoutes, { navigationOptions }));
}
```

AppNavigator.js

```js
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: {
        MainTabNavigator,
      },
    },
    ...ModalStack
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);


export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
    Main: MainStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  })
);
```

I expect the app to run without warning, but instead I'm getting a warning 'You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app'. As said earlier i tried moving the `generateNavigator()` to `AppNavigator` in order to solve the problem but with no success.

Comment: Which navigator is rendered when your app starts?

Comment: export default createAppContainer() is rendered when the app starts